# why can't I create an instance of MyVector ?

Tags: java, constructor

Given the following code , from some reason it won't create an instance of MyVector . What might be the problem ? The problem occurs in the line of Main :

```
MyVector vec = new MyVector();
```

However , when I create the an instance of MyVector with the other constructor :

```
MyVector vec2 = new MyVector(arr);
```

it compile and the instance is allocated.

class Dot:

```
public class Dot {

    private double dotValue;

    public Dot(double dotValue)
    {
        this.dotValue = dotValue;
    }

    public double getDotValue()
    {
        return this.dotValue;
    }

    public void setDotValue(double newDotValue)
    {
        this.dotValue = newDotValue;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "The Dot's value is :" + this.dotValue;
    }

}
```

class MyVector

```
public class MyVector {

    private Dot[] arrayDots;

    MyVector()
    {       
        int k = 2;
        this.arrayDots = new Dot[k];
    }

    public MyVector(int k)
    {
        this.arrayDots = new Dot[k];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < k)
            arrayDots[i].setDotValue(0);
    }

    public MyVector(double array[])
    {
        this.arrayDots = new Dot[array.length];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < array.length)
        {
            this.arrayDots[i] = new Dot(array[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }

}
```

and Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int k = 10;
        double [] arr = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
        System.out.println("Enter you K");
        MyVector vec = new MyVector();  // that line compile ,but when debugging it crashes , why ? 
        MyVector vec2 = new MyVector(arr);


    }
}
```

Regards
Ron

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: You can't initialize an array of objects this way `this.arrayDots = new Dot[k];` ... you have to use a for loop and initialize each index.

Comment: You need to provide the stack trace that the debugger gives you when your program "crashes".

Comment: @CoolBeans - Actually, you **can** initialize it that way.  It is just that you are initializing it to all `null` ... which may not be what you want / need.

Comment: @StephenC - right, that's what I meant. Thanks for clarifying it :)

Comment: It still doesn't work. I get ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: @ron - if you provided the stack trace (including the *full* error message) ... **like we asked you to** ... we wouldn't have to *guess* what the problem is.

Comment: Okay : ClassNotFoundException(Throwable).<init>(String, Throwable) line 286.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your code into my Eclipse IDE and got an "org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array." Exception when I click on the arrayDots variable.

Your code is ok and working. The debugger has a problem because the Dot class is not loaded.
See also: http://www.coderanch.com/t/433238/Testing/ClassNotLoadedException-Eclipse-debugger

You could change your Main as follows (I know this is not very beautiful)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int k = 10;
    double [] arr = {0,1,2,3,4,5};
    System.out.println("Enter you K");
    new Dot(); // the classloader loads the Dot class
    MyVector vec = new MyVector();  // that line compile ,but when debugging it crashes , why ? 
    MyVector vec2 = new MyVector(arr);


}
```

Comment: Hi,what does it mean "Dot class is not loaded" ? I've been working on c++ for three years , and this is my first week in Java , so I'm a newbie so please go easy on me...

Comment: In java the ClassLoader is responsible for loading the classes. This is done dynamically on demand, i.e. when the object is instantiated at the first time. This means "loaded". In your case no Dot object has created so far and hence it was not loaded by the ClassLoader. I never had a problem like this in my 5 year Java career ;-)

Comment: Okay , so what now ? throw Eclipse through the window ?

Comment: You can force the ClassLoader to load it by calling new Dot() before new Vector() as I suggested in my code or maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367730/how-do-i-deal-with-a-classnotloadedexception-while-debugging which deals with the same problem. Btw my debugger does not crash it simply shows the error message when you click on the arrayDots variable in the message area

Answer (score 2):

Your default constructor is not visible. Add public keyword in front of the constructor.