# Eclipse ClassNotLoadedException while testing array class type object

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, junit

**ERROR:**

org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array

**CAUSE:**

```
Typer[] typeResult;
for( String check : splitter )
{
  if ( check != null)
  {
    TypeResponse list = service.getGroup(name, id, value, db );
    typeResult = list.getCompany(); /* ERROR HERE */
    for ( int i = 0; i<typeResult.length; i++   )
    {
      String fvalue = typeResult[i].getCompManagerName();
    }
  }

}
```

ECLIPSE Java Compiler = 1.6
JAVA_HOME = 1.6

How can i tackle this ?

Comment: why do you have an empty `for(  ) {}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a ClassNotLoadedException while debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367730/how-do-i-deal-with-a-classnotloadedexception-while-debugging)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `service.getGroup(name, id, value, db )` is returning null or garbage value as service object itself is `NULL` here.