# libgdx catches all exceptions, only presents RuntimeException instead of original one

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to debug a libgdx application... Obviously, I'm producing a NullPointerException at some point, but libgdx has a huge try-catch statement that catches my original exception:

```
        public void run () {
            graphics.setVSync(graphics.config.vSyncEnabled);
            try {
                LwjglApplication.this.mainLoop();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                if (audio != null) audio.dispose();
                if (t instanceof RuntimeException)
                    throw (RuntimeException)t;
                else
                    throw new GdxRuntimeException(t);
            }
        }
```

So the debugger stops in the catch statement where the (Gdx)RuntimeException is thrown. I know that t contains the original exception, but I can't really tell where it came from. Is there any way to break at the line that produces that exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that worked: Add the exception that is shown in t to the list of exceptions that should always trigger the debugger, even when being catched:

[Break when exception is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066199/eclipse-break-when-exception-is-thrown)

Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

Untested with `libgdx` but in similar systems you might be able to do…

```
try {
    foo.run () 
} catch (RuntimeException t) {
    System.err.println ("** Caught a runtime exception.");
    t.printStackTrace();
    Throwable tCause = t;
    while (tCause = tCause.getCause()) {
         System.err.println("→ caused by:");
         t.getCause.printStackTrace ();
    }
}
```

It appears that `GdxException.GdxException (Throwable)` should call `super (t)` which in turn should “stash” `t` in the property for the `getCause` accessor.

PS: Have you tried running a static analyzer like FindBugs to locate potential NPE's?

Comment: t's cause field in this case is a reference to t itself. Also, the code I pasted was taken from the libgdx library, I'm trying to to mess with their source but just use it in order to not run into problems when they update.

/edit
Haven't ever used static analysers. I'll try FindBugs and see if that helps. I do still think that I should somehow be able to locate the source of an Exception that crashes my program though...

Comment: I wonder how they managed that? Very bizarre. You might want to switch to a different build of `libgdx` that doesn't have that particular bug.

Answer (score 0):

How about [inspecting the stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/stacktrace-to-string-in-java) and inserting a breakpoint where the `NullPointerException` is generated?

Comment: Yes, t's stacktrace would have been my first idea, too. The problem is that the stacktrace looks like this: "org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.". No further information. That doesn't exactly help me locating the point in my code that generates the NPE. As I said, I can't really tell where it came from, that's exactly what I'm trying to find out :-/

Comment: Sounds like eclipse is confused. Did you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367730/how-do-i-deal-with-a-classnotloadedexception-while-debugging)?

Comment: Not really... "Either you need to recompile to get the line numbers in sync or some other issue is going on" isn't really helping though. Cleaning up the projects and recompiling them doesn't change the issue.