# Invoke getter in java with reflections

Tags: java, reflection, getter

I want to invoke the getters with reflections. I tired it in this way:

```
for(PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : Introspector.getBeanInfo(this.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors()){

    Method m = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();

    if(m != null)
        System.out.println(m.invoke(this).toString());
}
```

I always get a NullPointerException in the line where i invoke the method.

The stacktrace of the exception:

```
org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array.
```

I searched for this problem, but I did not get a solution for this.

Comment: What is `this` and instance of? What is the name of `m`?

Comment: you didn't create the instance first...

Comment: I searched and found a remarkable [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1367730/3080094)

Comment: It is my own class, in this case `Block`. I have a lots of classes where I want to use this code. I tried it direclty in the Block class. If it would work I want to put it in the superclass, so I just need to write this method only once. In `m` there are all the getter methods. And I created the instance first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
if (args.length != 4) {
    err.format("Usage: java Deet <classname> <langauge> <country> <variant>%n");
    return;
}

try {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName(args[0]);
    Object t = c.newInstance();

    Method[] allMethods = c.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : allMethods) {
    String mname = m.getName();
    if (!mname.startsWith("test")
        || (m.getGenericReturnType() != boolean.class)) {
        continue;
    }
    Type[] pType = m.getGenericParameterTypes();
    if ((pType.length != 1)
        || Locale.class.isAssignableFrom(pType[0].getClass())) {
        continue;
    }

    out.format("invoking %s()%n", mname);
    try {
        m.setAccessible(true);
        Object o = m.invoke(t, new Locale(args[1], args[2], args[3]));
        out.format("%s() returned %b%n", mname, (Boolean) o);

    // Handle any exceptions thrown by method to be invoked.
    } catch (InvocationTargetException x) {
        Throwable cause = x.getCause();
        err.format("invocation of %s failed: %s%n",
               mname, cause.getMessage());
    }
    }

    // production code should handle these exceptions more gracefully
} catch (ClassNotFoundException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
}
```