# ClassNotLoadedException while initializing 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to implement a sudoku validator to see if the to be inserted number would be allowed.

I have a 2-d array of a class called FieldModel which at the moment only has an integer as an attribute and the getter and setter for it.
When I try to initialize my board, I notice in my Eclipse Debugger a "ClassNotLoadedException" which in the end results in a NPE (which I was expecting and tried to catch by using Objects.nonNull()).

I couldn't find a resonable answer which I understood and don't really understand why there is a problem like this in the first place and how I can "load" my class then. I tried just creating a dummy FieldModel object right before the loop, but that didn't help.

Here is the method itself, it flips out on the "if" in the first for-loop. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
public boolean checkIfValueInsertedLegal(FieldModel[][] board, int row, int column, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
        if (Objects.nonNull(board[row][i].getValue()) && board[row][i].getValue() == value) {
            System.out.println("Could not insert value in row: " + row + " and column: " + i);
            return false;
        }
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j++) {
        if (Objects.nonNull(board[row][j].getValue()) && board[j][column].getValue() == value) {
            System.out.println("Could not insert value in row: " + j + " and column: " + column);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367730/how-do-i-deal-with-a-classnotloadedexception-while-debugging

Comment: Yes, after looking more closely, that answer indeed helped.